# How to define a custom step value for vaadin-integer-field

Tags: vaadin, web-component

I am trying to pass `0.001` as a `step` value to `vaadin-integer-field` and I receive this browser console warning:

```
<vaadin-integer-field> The `step` property must be a positive integer but `0.001` was provided, so the property was reset to `null`.
```

Is there a way around this? If not, can I implement this? Or should I stop using vaadin and write my own integer field?

Comment: Think of it this way, you bought IKEA's BILLY and you want a half shelf width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a float step, you can use a

```
<vaadin-number-field label="Balance"></vaadin-number-field>
```

or by Flow

```
NumberField numberField = new NumberField("Test Num Field");
numberField.setStep(0.001);
```

see https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/tree/main/packages/number-field